# d3.scale.linear() vs d3.scaleLinear()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Hi I'm looking at the [**documentation**](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale) for scales and it shows a format like this `var x = d3.scaleLinear([10,130]).range([0,960])` I feel like this is strange because most [**examples**](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/e1aa61856118edfa624d) that I see online use something like this:

`var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([10,130]).range([0,960])` and it works.

If I use `var x = d3.scaleLinear([10,130]).range([0,960]);` I get an error like

> TypeError: d3.scaleLinear is not a function

Why do you think there is a discrepancy between the examples in the documentation and what I see in examples online? maybe I don't understand how to read documentation.

EDIT : [This](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales) is the current documentation for scales.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation you're looking at is for a plugin for D3 -- how to install it is described further down on that same page. It will eventually be part of the next major release of D3.

Answer (score 68):

To create a linear scale with d3.js ***version 3*** use API `d3.scale.linear()`

and to create a linear scale with ***version 4 and 5*** use API `d3.scaleLinear()`

API references for creating a linear scale for both the versions can be found here:

[v3.x scale.linear](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Quantitative-Scales.md#linear)

[v4.x scaleLinear](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleLinear)

Comment: I had the same problem using CodePen, where I was watching an older video that was using version 3, but CodePen uses 4+. To find which version you are using simply type `d3 -v` in the project directory.

Answer (score 6):

They are doing exactly the same thing, but it's just code change happen to `D3.js` from **version 3** to **version 4**...

So linear is not property of scale object of **d3** framework anymore...

instead it's part of d3 with **camelCase** syntax...

So `d3.js` **v3** use `d3.scale.linear()`

and to create a linear scale with **v4** use `d3.scaleLinear()` instead...

**version 3:**

> **d3.scale.linear()**
>
> Constructs a new linear scale with the default domain [0,1] and the
>   default range [0,1]. Thus, the default linear scale is equivalent to
>   the identity function for numbers; for example linear(0.5) returns
>   0.5.

**version 4:**

> **d3.scaleLinear()**
>
> Constructs a new continuous scale with the unit domain [0, 1], the
>   unit range [0, 1], the default interpolator and clamping disabled.
>   Linear scales are a good default choice for continuous quantitative
>   data because they preserve proportional differences. Each range value
>   y can be expressed as a function of the domain value x: y = mx + b.

Answer (score 3):

As specified by Hina, d3.scale.linear() is used on D3 3.0, and d3 4.0 adopted the flat namespace convention. Here is a snippet from the d3 changelog summary

> If you don’t care about modularity, you can mostly ignore this change and keep using the default bundle. However, there is one unavoidable consequence of adopting ES6 modules: every symbol in D3 4.0 now shares a flat namespace rather than the nested one of D3 3.x. For example, d3.scale.linear is now d3.scaleLinear,...

Source: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md

EDIT: Forgot to mention - to fix your error, you may have to update the link or file to d3 that you have in your program. I call it directly from the website with:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```