# variable with .select method returns null - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My apologies if this is a duplicate post. I promise that I did a search for similar, but it's late and I'm tired. Also, this seems like a total NOOB question.

So I'm working on a horizontal bar chart in D3 and I'm appending an SVG to my #wrapper and then I follow it up with a new variable that includes `.append('g')`. Pretty standard. But my `.select` method returns null and console throws up

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null".

What's up? How do I get my svg element to populate with g elements?

```
    var canvas = d3.select('#wrapper')
        .append('svg')
        .attr({'width':900,'height':550});

    var grids = canvas.append('g') 
        .attr('id','grid')
        .attr('transform','translate(150,10)')
        .selectAll('line')
        .data(grid)
        .enter()
        .append('line')
        .attr({'x1':function(d,i){return i*30;},
            'y1': function(d){return d.y1;},
            'x2': function(d,i){return i*30;},
            'y2': function(d){return d.y2;},
            })
        .style({'stroke':'#adadad','stroke-width':'1px'});
```

JS Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/ntos9hwz/

Answer (score 0):

Found multiple mistakes in your code.

1. `var transittext = d3.select("#bars")`. There is no element with `#bars` id in your html. You should get the element and give it to `select()` function. i.e

   ```
   var elem = document.getElementById("#wrapper")
   var trasittext = d3.select()
   ```
2. there is no function called `scaleLinear()` on d3. It's `scale.linear()`
3. there is no function called `scaleQuantize()` on d3. It's `scale.quantize()`
4. and on 45th line you wrote `.tickVals(tickVals);`. It is `.tickValues(tickVals);`

After all changes, here is your working code

```js
 var categories = [" ",'Accessories', 'Audiophile', 'Camera & Photo', 'Cell Phones', 'Computers','eBook Readers','Gadgets','GPS & Navigation','Home Audio','Office Electronics','Portable Audio','Portable Video','Security & Surveillance','Service','Television & Video','Car & Vehicle'];
  var dollars = [213,209,190,179,156,209,190,179,213,209,190,179,156,209,190,190];
  var colors = ['#0000b4','#0082ca','#0094ff','#0d4bcf','#0066AE','#074285','#00187B','#285964','#405F83','#416545','#4D7069','#6E9985','#7EBC89','#0283AF','#79BCBF','#99C19E'];
  
  var grid = d3.range(25).map(function(i){
   return {'x1':0, 'y1':0,'x2':0,'y2':0};
  });
 
  var tickVals = grid.map(function(d,i){
   if(i>0){return i*10;}
   else if (i===0){return "100";}
  });

  var xscale = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain([10,250])
   .range([0,722])
  var yscale = d3.scale.linear()
   .domain([0, categories.length])
   .range([0,7450]);
  var colorScale = d3.scale.quantize()
   .domain([0, categories.length])
   .range(colors);
  var canvas = d3.select('#wrapper')
   .append('svg')
   .attr({'width':900,'height':550});

  var grids = canvas.append('g') 
   .attr('id','grid')
   .attr('transform','translate(150,10)')
   .selectAll('line')
   .data(grid)
   .enter()
   .append('line')
   .attr({'x1':function(d,i){return i*30;},
    'y1': function(d){return d.y1;},
    'x2': function(d,i){return i*30;},
    'y2': function(d){return d.y2;},
    })
   .style({'stroke':'#adadad','stroke-width':'1px'});

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis(); 
   xAxis
   .orient('bottom')
   .scale(xscale)
   .tickValues(tickVals);
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis();
   yAxis
   .orient('left')
   .scale(yscale)
   .tickSize(2)
   .tickFormat(function(d,i){return categories[i];})
   .tickValues(d3.range(17));
  var y_xis = canvas.append('g')
   .attr("transform","translate(150,0)") 
   .attr('id','yaxis')
   .call(yAxis);
  var x_xis = canvas.append('g')
   .attr("transform","translate(150,480)")
   .attr('id','xaxis')
   .call(xAxis);

  var chart = canvas.append('g')
   .attr("transform","translate(150,0)")
   .attr('id','bars')
   .selectAll('rect')
   .data(dollars)
   .enter()
   .append('rect')
   .attr('height',19)
   .attr({'x':0,'y':function(d,i){return yscale(i)+19; }})
   .style('fill',function(d,i){return colorScale(i); })
   .attr('width',function(d){return 0; });

  var elemxyz = document.getElementById("wrappet");
  var transittext = d3.select(elemxyz)
   .selectAll('text')
   .data(dollars)
   .enter()
   .append('text')
   .attr({'x':function(d) {return xscale(d)-200;}, 'y': function(d,i){return yscale(i)+35; }})
   .text(function(d){return d+"$"; }).style({'fill':'#fff','font-size':'14px'});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

**Updated**

To create a linear scale with d3.js version 3, use [**d3.scale.linear()**](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Quantitative-Scales.md#linear)

and to create a linear scale with d3.js version 4, use [**d3.scaleLinear()**](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleLinear)

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hey, cool, thanks. I'll take a closer look. Real quick on #2 and #3. scale.Linear and scale.Quantize were throwing errors as well. My understanding is the D3 version 4 changed these to scaleLinear and scaleQuantize. When I corrected my errors cleared. Do you have documentation that suggests otherwise? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953892/d3-scale-linear-vs-d3-scalelinear