# How to rename a function linear() in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use D3 library v5.7.0. Live demo [is here](http://jsfiddle.net/zlodiak/0u9pLvsx/3/).

But console display follow error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'linear' of undefined

My js code:

```
// init data
const w = 1000;
const h = 300;

const dataset = [
  [ 5,     20000 ],
  [ 20,   120000 ],
  [ 20,   88000 ]
];

// scale
const scale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([0, 160000])
                    .range([10, 350]);
```

Please help fix it.

Comment: Why would you want to _"rename"_ a function? How will this help that `d3.scale` is `undefined`? O.o

Comment: `d3.scale.linear()` will only work until v3, since v4 it is `d3.scaleLinear()`: [javascript - d3.scale.linear() vs d3.scaleLinear()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35953892/d3-scale-linear-vs-d3-scalelinear)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a comment said, `de.linear()` only will works until the `v3`, as you are working with the `v5` if you print in console the `d3 object` will see the `scale` object is not there.

So replace the object`d3.scale.linear()` by [`d3.scaleLinear()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleLinear).

More info here: https://github.com/d3/d3-scale

Comment: "change...to..." or "replace...with..." :-) (Just FWIW. And I guarantee your English is better than my whatever-your-native-language-is. :-) )